# Xubuntu with custom kernel : why is it using configuration from /boot?

Tags: kernel, xubuntu

I've downloaded the latest stable Linux kernel source (3.9.4), I'm running Xubuntu 13.04. I'd like to try to build my own kernel, as I'm quite comfortable at my hardware.

As suggested, I did the following:

```
root@localhost:/usr/src/linux-3.9.4# make clean
root@localhost:/usr/src/linux-3.9.4# make mrproper
root@localhost:/usr/src/linux-3.9.4# touch .config
root@localhost:/usr/src/linux-3.9.4# make menuconfig
```

I'm using `touch .config` because, without it, it's using some configuration from `/boot`. Why?

Comment: You /should/ use the default configuration from /boot, at least as a base for your customization. Otherwise, checking the dozens (hundreds?) of options in menuconfig will take a lot of time. And your question makes me wonder whether you even have enough knowledge to do that.

Comment: @ignis well I know. I know i can use `make defconfig` o use any previous configuration as base. But my actual question is: why is using that from `/boot` as base?